# Navigate multiple browsers in one command Visual Basic

Tags: vba, browser

So, if I have for example three webbrowsers and I want them all to navigate to google.com I have to do it like this:

```
 webbrowser1.navigate("google.com")
 webbrowser2.navigate("google.com")
 webbrowser3.navigate("google.com")
```

Is it possible do it in one line of code?

Comment: `webbrowser1.navigate("google.com"):webbrowser2.navigate("google.com"):webbrowser3.navigate("google.com")`

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. Once you've posted a question, you have licensed the content to the Stack Overflow community at large (under the CC-by-SA license).  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323395/what-is-the-proper-route-for-a-dissociation-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an **Array** along with a **for** loop as follows.

```
Dim webbrowser(3) As WebBrowser
    For value As Integer = 0 To 3
        webbrowser(value) = New WebBrowser
        webbrowser(value).Navigate("www.google.com")
    Next
```

**Note:-** For only 3 instances, this code may not be necessary, but for 30 it might definitely help.

Answer (score 1):

A sub routine:

```
NavigateTo "google.com"
```

Which calls

```
sub NavigateTo(url as string)
    webbrowser1.navigate(url)
    webbrowser2.navigate(url)
    webbrowser3.navigate(url)
end sub
```